# Multiple integrations of a data-function over a small portion of its domain - accuracy and efficiency

Tags: python, algorithm, math, numpy, scipy

As part of my research, I'm required to integrate data-defined functions over small subsets of their domain, many times over. This is a long post: answers to any of the three questions below will be acknowledged!

For example, let's say I have a large 1-D domain `x`, and a function `y` to be integrated over some subset of `x`.

In a typical example, the domain `x` would have 1000 grid points, where at step '`i`' my data function `y[i,:]` is a numpy array the same size as `x`. Typically `y` will be a numpy array of shape `(1000,1000)`.

Now, for each value of `i`, I need to employ quadrature, for many points in `x`, to find the integral of `y[i,arr]` over `arr`, where `arr` is a subdomain of `x`.

Here's my first problem: when `arr` is small (say 3 points), methods like `scipy.integrate.cumtrapz` won't give a good approximation - there are only three values in `y[i,arr]`.

At each step `i`, one has to do such integrations for `arr`'s ranging from size 3 to approximately size 200. The output of these integrations are used to update `y[i+1,:]`, so I believe much error is being introduced due to my current use of `cumtrapz`.

Edit: Many thanks to @Fabian Rost, who provided an answer to what was Question 1: whether errors were in fact being introduced. He also proposed a using linear interpolation as in Question 2 below, and an estimate for how long such a technique would take. I guess what really remains is whether there is a faster technique than that proposed.

My proposed solution is to:

1. Create a new interpolating object, say `y2`, for `y[i,arr2]`, where `arr2` is a sufficiently larger subdomain than `arr`.
2. Create a new linspace `x2` corresponding to the intersection of `arr` with `arr2`, then use an existing function-integration method like `scipy.integrate.quadrature` to integrate `y2` over `x2`.
3. The result from step 2 is probably a really good approximation to the integral for `y[i,arr]`.

Question 2: Are all these steps necessary? That is, is there a built-in that will do all this for me?

Question 3: I believe if I want to avoid errors, I have to do these interpolations->integrations, over 1000 iterations, for at least 200 subdomains at each iteration. This can clearly become quite costly. Is there a more Pythonic way to do this?

Answers to any of these questions are GREATLY appreciated! Thanks so much for reading.

Comment: Integrating a data-defined function with just 3 points given is always error prone. Or do you have any idea for a good interpolation function? Do you simply mean linear interpolation in your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming linear interpolation is a good model you could define a continuous data function and integrate using `scipy.integrate.quad` like that:

```
import scipy as sp
import scipy.integrate

xp = sp.linspace(0, 1000, 1000)
yp = sp.randn(1000)

datafunc = lambda x: sp.interp(x, xp, yp)

sp.integrate.quad(datafunc, 3, 1000)
```

Depending on the domain size the integration take 2 to 4 ms on my machine. That would mean something like 4 hours for 1000 * 200 integrations which I think is OK, if you only need to do it once. But the time will heavily depend on your data.

Comment: Very interesting to hear. This process is actually one step in the full problem, where there's more computations (fast though) at each iteration, so an estimate of about 4 hours just for the integration means I need something faster.  I'm upvoting this because I really appreciate the quantitative estimate, and the answer to Question 1. If linear interpolation is fastest it'll have to do, thanks.

Comment: Oh and I forgot to mention you proposed a solution to Question 2, using builtins. Thanks very much for that.

Comment: (+1) Style nitpick: you almost never want `import scipy as sp`. Better import `interp`, `linspace` et al from `numpy` directly.